# Assigning current time stamp to a variable

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I am trying to store the reception of some data timestamp to a variable like this:

```
DateTime timetora = DateTime.Now;
DateTime receptiontimestamp;
receptiontimestamp = timetora;
```

but I think that as `timetora` is always progressing `receptiontimestamp` does the same. But I want it to remain constant and point to the reception moment not the present.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ll have to check whether all receptions happend at the same second. Because thats what it showed. Any way thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't continue "progressing"

When you do:

```
DateTime timetora = DateTime.Now;
```

timetora is now fixed to that time (And so is any other DateTime you set to timetora) There's nothing wrong with what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've given will copy the value from `timetora` to `receptiontimestamp`. It *won't* keep progressing. For example:

```
DateTime before = DateTime.Now;
Thread.Sleep(10000);
DateTime after = before;

Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", before);
Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", after);
```

Both lines will show the same time - they *won't* show ten seconds difference. As far as I can tell, that's what you wanted, right?

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a value type, so

```
DateTime timetora = DateTime.Now;
```

creates a copy of the current DateTime. timetora will not have increased when you access it later.